# Remove negative words from sentences

Tags: ruby

The `neutralize` method below is intended to remove negative words from sentences.

```
def neutralize(sentence)
  words = sentence.split(' ')
  words.each do |word|
    words.delete(word) if negative?(word)
  end
  words.join(' ')
end

def negative?(word)
  [
    'dull',
    'boring',
    'annoying',
    'chaotic'
  ].include?(word)
end
```

However, it fails to remove all of them. Whereas I expected to get:

```
"These cards are part of a board game."
```

I got the following result:

```
neutralize('These dull boring cards are part of a chaotic board game.')
# => "These boring cards are part of a board game."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using `delete_if`?

```
def neutralize(sentence)
  words = sentence.split(' ')
  words.delete_if { |word| negative? word }
  words.join(' ')
end

def negative?(word)
  [ 'dull', 'boring', 'annoying', 'chaotic' ].include? word
end

puts neutralize('These dull boring cards are part of a chaotic board game.')
```

Modifying the array you are iterating on can cause issues. For example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.each { |i| a.delete i }
p a
# => [2, 4]
```

You should avoid it under most circumstances.

To better understand why the output is like it is, see this example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a.each_with_index do |item, index|
  puts "deleting item #{item} at index #{index}:"
  a.delete item
  p a
end
```

Comment: What is the reason that delete_if works and delete() doesn't?

Comment: See my updated answer, hopefully it now explains why. Experiment with the simple last example of the result, to see how the iterator gets "confused" when you mess with its subject.